# refactoring if a < b: a = b

Tags: python, refactoring

there must be an easy way to refactor the below statement:

```
if date_extracted < data_registered:
    date_registered = date_extracted
```

it seems so trivial but I do this so many times in my code base, it becomes like refactoring

```
a = a + 1  into  a += 1
```

Comment: `date_registered = min(date_registered, date_extracted)` is basically what you are after is it not

Comment: and this min function works on dates, strings, dicts and what not.  And if you really have a specific data structure, you can always write your own min function: I Knew there was an easier way!! tnx